# How do I write implementations for an application that uses ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

I've been tasked with integrating an existing application with another application that uses ServiceStack to expose its API's to the outside world.

I can get to the metadata page (at /metadata) and it talks about the responses that can be received from the endpoint.  Cool.

The thing is, how do I generate services that can query this endpoint and return a result?  I know I can roll my own, mainly, to query the endpoints and then deserialise the response into a object that is based on the XSD's that ServiceStack provides.  But I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel.

With some guessing, if I go to /metadata/soap12 I get a WSDL that has these bindings in them:

```
<wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply" type="svc:ISyncReply">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_IOneWay" type="svc:IOneWay">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="SyncReply">
<wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply" binding="svc:WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply">
<soap:address location="https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Services/soap12"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
<wsdl:service name="AsyncOneWay">
<wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_IOneWay" binding="svc:WSHttpBinding_IOneWay">
<soap:address location="https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Services/soap12"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Obviously I would be expecting a lot more.  The application is question exposes a Search route in its API documentation (at /metadata) so I would expect to see a WSDL service that utilises that utlises that action and returns a result.

Is there any way to get a generated set of POCO's from a ServiceStack application, and also a set of services that I can invoke? I know in WCF I can do this if I point svcutil.exe to a WSDL.

Sorry if this question is poorly formed or reads weirdly - I'm new to using ServiceStack.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a C# Application it's highly recommended to use the much faster and cleaner ServiceStack's [Add C# Service Reference](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-add-servicestack-reference) support instead of generating types with [SOAP/WSDL](https://www.infoq.com/articles/interview-servicestack).

This will generate Typed DTOs which you can use with [ServiceStack's .NET Service Clients](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client).

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying!  I've tried that (to add a C# reference) and I get a 404 error.  Using fiddler, it's trying to access /metadata/types/csharp which doesn't exist.

Comment: @LewisCianci you should only be entering in the `BaseUrl` i.e. the url before `/metadata`. You can also download [different languages from these paths](http://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference#language-paths) directly, e.g. for C# it's `/types/csharp`.

Comment: That also 404's. I have a theory that maybe its a really really old version of ServiceStack that doesn't have that functionality.  Could that be it or do I have it wrong?

Comment: @LewisCianci What version does the `X-Powered-By` HTTP Header on the HTTP Response say?

Comment: x-powered-by →ServiceStack/3.943 Win32NT/.NET, ASP.NET

Comment: @LewisCianci Yep that's a very old primitive version [released in 4/1/2013](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack). If they can give you the ServiceModel.dll or DTO classes you can get the Types that way, otherwise I'd be manually calling the JSON APIs using a [generic HTTP Client like HTTP Utils](http://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils).